# How to solve battery power only updated on boot

Tags: power-management, battery

I use Lenovo Yoga and installed Ubuntu. So I find that my laptop battery isn't accurate. I have used it for some times and it show 95%. But when i reboot it, it shows 60%. I put it on charge and it still show 60%, but if I reboot it again it shows 80%. So the battery level only updated on reboot.

This is my battery detail:
[image]

Somehow the discharge accuracy is 0%

[image]

I try to use  `power-calliberate` and get:

```
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$ power-calibrate 
The battery just provided charge data which is not accurate enough.
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$ power-calibrate  -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p
Device does not have any RAPL domains, cannot power measure power usage.
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$
```

My CPU is:

```
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep CPU
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

Is it a problem in OS level? I try in Lubuntu but still the same. I guess it still debian, or this is the problem in hardware level?